# Deploying profiles from two unconnected orgs

Tags: profile, ant, deployment

I wanted to know, if I could deploy some profiles from two orgs that are not connected, through Java - Ant procedure. Actually, one org is a sandbox and the other is a production/developer.

The orgs, contain the same data model, custom objects and business logic.

Please, let me know if further dettails are needed.

Thanks in advance!
Endrit.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that would stop you from doing it. You obviously can't do it using ChangeSets but you can definitely do that using IDE or Java/ ANT or SnapShot (Disclaimer: I work for DreamFactory).

Just ensure that there are no collisions with respect to features turned on or off between the two Orgs. Else, you will end up editing the profile XML a bunch.

Good luck!

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply.
Actually I am studying and working on how could Java/Ant apporach, could help me. I felt, I needed a confirm about that, that's why I asked. 
Thank you.